# Setting up Google Drive API in Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have been trying to set up a very simple python program to connect to Google Drive API, I have tried dozens of different approaches I found online but none seem to be working, documentation is all over the place and I cant get it to work.

I am in need of an approach that does not prompt the user to grant access seeing that I am going to be accessing my own personal drive, I would like it to do it automatically without me having to accept every time.

Could anyone send me a complete (very simplistic) working code template that I can use to connect to googles drive API using python?

This is my latest attempt, you might modify this one or create a new one, I just need it to work :(

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow, FlowExchangeError

# Use the client_secret.json file to identify the application requesting
# authorization. The client ID (from that file) and access scopes are required.
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'])

# Indicate where the API server will redirect the user after the user completes
# the authorization flow. The redirect URI is required.
flow.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/'

# Generate URL for request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
# Use kwargs to set optional request parameters.
authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
    # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
    # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
    access_type='offline',
    # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
    include_granted_scopes='true')

print(state)

# code = input('Enter verification code: ').strip()

try:
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(state)
    print(json.dumps(json.loads(credentials._to_json([])), sort_keys=True, indent=4))
except FlowExchangeError:
    print("Your verification code is incorrect or something else is broken.")
    exit(1)
```

Bonus: I am going to use this to upload a CSV file and then edit the same file with new data

Thanks alot for all the help.

Comment: If you want an automated uploading of files, try using service account to impersonate your account as service account is consider as a separate user (having their own email or more likely a virtual user) as described in this [blog](https://ctrlq.org/code/20364-google-service-accounts-introduction). You can check out this [tutorial](https://shocksolution.com/2018/04/23/service-account-credentials-python-client-google-drive-api-v3/), with a [code](https://github.com/cfinch/Shocksolution_Examples/blob/master/GoogleCloudPlatform/driveAPIexample.py) that shares the create file to a human user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a service account.  Service accounts are like dummy users.  A service account has its own drive account which you can access programticlly and upload and download to and from.  You can also share a folder or folders on your own google drive account with the server account.  There by per-authorizing it and giving it permissions to access your drive account.   There will be no consent screen or login screen displayed

The main difference is the login methods.  I dont see a python service account drive example but there is one for google analytics api.   If you take a look at that it shouldn't be to hard to alter it.  You will need to make service account credentials the credentials file you have now will not work.

[Hello Analytics API: Python quickstart for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-py)

```
"""A simple example of how to access the Google Analytics API."""

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


def get_service(api_name, api_version, scopes, key_file_location):
    """Get a service that communicates to a Google API.

    Args:
        api_name: The name of the api to connect to.
        api_version: The api version to connect to.
        scopes: A list auth scopes to authorize for the application.
        key_file_location: The path to a valid service account JSON key file.

    Returns:
        A service that is connected to the specified API.
    """

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
            key_file_location, scopes=scopes)

    # Build the service object.
    service = build(api_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    return service


def get_first_profile_id(service):
    # Use the Analytics service object to get the first profile id.

    # Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
    accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

    if accounts.get('items'):
        # Get the first Google Analytics account.
        account = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')

        # Get a list of all the properties for the first account.
        properties = service.management().webproperties().list(
                accountId=account).execute()

        if properties.get('items'):
            # Get the first property id.
            property = properties.get('items')[0].get('id')

            # Get a list of all views (profiles) for the first property.
            profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
                    accountId=account,
                    webPropertyId=property).execute()

            if profiles.get('items'):
                # return the first view (profile) id.
                return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')

    return None


def get_results(service, profile_id):
    # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Core Reporting API
    # for the number of sessions within the past seven days.
    return service.data().ga().get(
            ids='ga:' + profile_id,
            start_date='7daysAgo',
            end_date='today',
            metrics='ga:sessions').execute()


def print_results(results):
    # Print data nicely for the user.
    if results:
        print 'View (Profile):', results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
        print 'Total Sessions:', results.get('rows')[0][0]

    else:
        print 'No results found'


def main():
    # Define the auth scopes to request.
    scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
    key_file_location = '<REPLACE_WITH_JSON_FILE>'

    # Authenticate and construct service.
    service = get_service(
            api_name='analytics',
            api_version='v3',
            scopes=[scope],
            key_file_location=key_file_location)

    profile_id = get_first_profile_id(service)
    print_results(get_results(service, profile_id))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The main thing you will need to change in the code is the scope api name and version.  Once you have a drive service created the code will be the same as the Oauth2 format.